# Audio Flickering on Bluetooth Device from My Android App

Tags: java, android, audio, bluetooth, flicker

I have an Android app which is basically a Player. My users sometimes uses my app with a connected Bluetooth device like Speaker, Headphone, Car etc.

I have no special code to use or manage Bluetooth. But since Android OS managing it, my users able to use Bluetooth devices without any development from my side.

Lately i got some feedback that my app not playing well on Bluetooth devices and sound freezing or flickering. And they are saying they have no problems with other apps like Spotify, Youtube etc. Also i could not find any issue in my tests.

So any idea what problem can be? Is there anything i can implement to prevent it. Is there any way that i can reproduce that problem?

Comment: It's often a problem related to the Bluetooth devices. Sometimes I have these problems with official music players (Sony, Google etc) on a Ford car, so... Have you asked them to check if other bluetooth apps work?

Comment: Sorry, i forget to mention that they are not facing same problem with Spotify, Youtube etc.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know it will fix the issue. But for a try, can you please provide the following permission in your app's AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
```

Comment: I believe that permissions related to manage Bluetooth configuration etc. Since i can use connected Bluetooth devices without any special permission right now with my app.